# Geometry textbooks

Tags: geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation

I have been searching for geometry textbooks that deals with elementary things like Congruence, Arc, Geometric shapes like triangles and so on. Any recommendations?

Comment: The book by Coxeter and Greitzer is good.

Comment: @Hilbert: I suppose you mean a first textbook in geometry? If not, let me know and I will update my answer.

Comment: Yes, first textbook!

Comment: @5space - I put done a order for both of the books! Hope your right

Comment: They are challenging, but very good books. If you need any help, don't hesitate to ask here!

Comment: @5space - Will do.I going on a limb here but you have them, right? Do the problems have answer only or does the solutions also follow?

Comment: @Hilbert: Yes, I own the books. The exercises do not have solutions, but you can always ask here if you are uncertain or need help!

Comment: Geometry Revisited by Coxeter,followed by Introduction To Geometry by Coxeter. You might want to have a look at Foundations Of Geometry by Hilbert.

Answer (score 3):

Very good, highly reputed Russian texts (translated, of course):

-Kiselev's [Planimetry](http://www.sumizdat.org/geom1.html) & [Stereometry](http://www.sumizdat.org/geom2.html)

Those two blow the rest out of the water in my opinion.

If you're interested in more "modern" textbooks and are at all interested in math competitions:

-Art of Problem Solving [Geometry](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Store/viewitem.php?item=intro%3ageometry)

Some people like the first edition of Jacob's [Geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008T1U6YW) book. It's okay (and better than most), but I like the above books much more.

Another alternative is [Geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387966544) by Lang and Murrow. I personally don't like Lang's exposition, but it works for some people.

And of course, you could always read Euclid's [Elements](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&sqi=2&ved=0CGsQFjAK&url=http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/euclid/elements.pdf&ei=cW5xUpeQDaGFiAL5tYHADw&usg=AFQjCNGYY8mXum5-aK2by6XtVg7Im9Coww&sig2=JS6YbnZsplmzn_0OMh6dgQ).

Comment: The Penguin Dictionary of Curious and Interesting Geometry
by David Wells should be supplementary reading.

Comment: Nice, I had never heard of that book. Geometry and the Imagination is good, too!